# Algunos comandos at no se ejecutan (Linux)

Tags: linux

Algunos comandos at no se ejecutan (Linux)

```
    echo 'mplayer test.mp3' | at now + 1 min  # Funciona, puedo oirlo.
    echo 'mplayer test.mp4' | at now + 1 min  # No funciona
    echo 'sudo pkill firefox' | at now + 1 min  # Funciona, cierra firefox
    echo 'echo "Hi" ' | at now + 1 min  # No funciona
    echo 'leafpad ' | at now + 1 min  # No funciona
```

Con sonido, o audio, funciona. Con gráficos, o la pantalla, no funciona. Qué pasa?

Comment: Hello, this is the spanish version of StackOverflow, maybe you are looking for the [english version](https://stackoverflow.com/) of the site or you can translate your question too. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Puede ocurrir que en la variable de entorno `PATH` no se encuentren las rutas de los binarios que estás ejecutando. Utiliza el comando `WICH` para conocer la ruta donde se encuentra el instalado el programa y añadelo a la variable `PATH`. Si no tienes conocimiento acerca de la variable `PATH` y como manipularla puedes informarte en:

https://blog.carreralinux.com.ar/2016/12/uso-de-variables-de-entorno-en-linux-ejemplos/